# Focus issues, focus sometimes goes to unknown object

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3

> [FocusEvent type="focusIn" bubbles=true cancelable=false eventPhase=3 relatedObject=null shiftKey=false keyCode=0]

When I click with a mouse an TextField, I would like that another (editable) field gets focus, but currently focus is lost somewhere.. I dont know where focus is.

I made a listener to textfield which tries to set focus back to another filed with stage.focus = editfield  but its not working.

I have also same focus listener in stage, but no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you list a "FocusEvent" in your example, I will focus on Flex solutions.  That is not a Flash AS3 class.

I will wager that Flex is trying to manage the focus by itself and that is screwing with your attempts to set it.  There are, however, a number of ways around this.

**Is Flex trying to work against you?**
First, you may want to either use FocusManager class or the UIComponent setFocus method (this depends on what you specifically need to do, I believe the FocusManager allows you to have multiple objects targeted, while the setFocus method is a good deal simpler) instead of stage.focus.  This has the benefit of working natively within the Flex component system.

**Are you listening to the right event?**
Failing that, try making sure that the target of the FocusEvent you're looking for is neither your textfield nor a child of your textfield.  (Just for sanity's sake). If that does not work, make sure you are only getting the event dispatched once.Next, I would try using MouseEvent.CLICK instead of a FocusEvent.

**Has everything else failed?**
Unfortunately, Flex is often far from perfect.  I find that sometimes I have to use setTimeout to get around the fact that it does not fire events in the "right order" -- you resize something, but "RESIZE" is dispatched before it has re-rendered, you change the font, and a TextArea's TextWidth property doesn't return the right number.  The workaround

```
private function myListener( event:FocusEvent ):null
{
    setTimeout( function(){ editfield.setFocus(); }, 35 );
}
```